# Could not compile `http`: process didn't exit successfully with signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When running my projects which has a dependency that requires http 0.1.13, cargo stops when trying to compile it.

It was compiling just fine on my one computer, but when I went to run my project on another machine cargo exits with "Could not compile `http`":

> process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name http /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/http-0.1.13/src/lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=60ef54382f532dbf -C extra-filename=-60ef54382f532dbf --out-dir /root/server-coordinator/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/root/server-coordinator/target/debug/deps --extern bytes=/root/server-coordinator/target/debug/deps/libbytes-951afda431db1a1b.rlib --extern fnv=/root/server-coordinator/target/debug/deps/libfnv-140d1d3e6e17478d.rlib --extern itoa=/root/server-coordinator/target/debug/deps/libitoa-3473eacee051d37a.rlib --cap-lints allow` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)

How can I figure out what the problem is? I'm running it on a VPS and the Linux kernel is 2.6 so I'm thinking it might have something to do with outdated compiler software.

Comment: _"it might have something to do with outdated compiler software"_ — what version of Rust are you using?

Comment: How much memory does your VPS have? I'd expect that you are running out of memory.

Comment: Rust version 1.29.0

Comment: It's very low, 256MB. It's just a very minimal web server that I want to run on it.

Comment: Can you run this command: `dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'`? Does it show rustc being killed? If that's the case, then Shepmaster is right, the system is out of memory.

Comment: Yes sir: `# dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'`
[21567294.020606] Out of memory in UB 3063: OOM killed process 558 (rustc) score 0 vm:582256kB, rss:212384kB, swap:57060kB

Comment: Anyways, I'm working around it by building on a different server now

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error. Reinstalling (uninstall & fresh install) the rust compiler solved the issue for me, you can also give it a try.